# Проблемы с версткой на Safari

Tags: html, css

Как писать стили под сафари? Все что я нахожу в интернете работает на сафари и на хроме, или вообще не работает.

Использовал:

```
[if lt Safari]
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php //echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/safari.css" media="screen, projection" />
![endif]


body:first-of-type .class{}

html:root*.class {}

html*.class {}
```

Но ничего не помогает.

Сам главный стиль загружается так

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
```

Стоит заметить что тест провожу на Safari под Windows. Возможности использовать Mac нету)

Comment: Он уже сильно старый, не уверен, что имеет смысл вообще в нём тестировать.

Comment: @fori1ton как же тогда тестить??

Answer (score 1):

1. Забудьте про Safari под винду. Современный крутой сафари на маке пашет не хуже хрома. Так что в 99,9% тестировать в нем нужно только из-за того, что под маком шрифты рендерятся по другому, и тексты получаются пошире. В остальном, если в Хроме все хорошо, то будет хорошо и в Сафари.
2. [if lt Safari] - так не бывает. Conditional Comments - это фишечка только у IE до 10 версии. Другие браузеры вообще кладут болт на это.
3. В целом, чтобы потестить Сафари, не обязателен Мак. Можно просто взять iPad/iPhone.

Comment: Проблема в том, что на Хроме все отлично, а заказчик тестит на iphone и у него лезет верстка.

Comment: В Chrome Developer Tools можно включить мобильные устройства и посмотреть как выглядит сайт на различных девайсах.

Comment: Конечно же на iPhone будут проблемы. Но потестить можно. Например в ФФ: меню -> разработка -> адаптивный дизайн или же в Хроме тоже есть такая фишечка в панели разработки.

Comment: "Не хуже хрома" - достаточно спорное заявление. Буквально на днях сталкивался с тем, что Safari 8 (самый распространённый на данный момент) ряд фишек CSS3 (transformations, animations, flexbox) поддерживает только с префиксами (http://caniuse.com/ в помощь). Проверку сайта в Safari без макоси можно осуществить при помощи сервисов проверки сайтов в разных браузерах. Большинство из них платные, но у многих есть free trial.

Comment: @fori1ton, Префиксы нельзя относить к проблемам. Если собираете проект с помощью Grunt/Gulp то всегда нужно пользоваться плагинами вроде autoprefixer и не париться об этом вообще.

Comment: @maxprof, если планируете продуктивно работать, то я вам очень рекомендую завести пару мобильных девайсов для тестирования.